# React HOC with Router not finding page

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am working on a react app with Routing and HOC. I expect to see a page but i get page not found when i know the page is there.
in componentDidMount this.setState, data is shown as undefined but in the HOC wrapper i see the data arrive from the server.

Before I wrapped the page in HOC i could see it rendering content so I know the content exists.

Here is my Page component which is being called via a Route :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import WithBackend from "./WithBackend";

class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { model: null };
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.model != null) {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md">
              <h1>{this.state.model.title}</h1>              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = this.props.getPage("1");
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({
      model: data,
    });
  }

}

export default WithBackend(Page);
```

Here is the HOC component WithBackend: I am not sure if i should be setting the state on this class on in the class that is being wrapped.
When i debug the code in the getPage method, in the setState part i see the data being populated from the backend server.

```js
import React from "react";
import ContentService from "./ContentService";

const WithBackend = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.contentService = new ContentService();
      this.getPage = this.getPage.bind(this); // <-- Add this
    }

    getPage(id) {
      this.contentService
        .getPage(id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ model: data });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent getPage={this.getPage} {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return HOC;
};

export default WithBackend;
```

and here is the contentService which only returns a promise:

```js
class ContentService {
  pageUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + "/pages/";

  getPage(id) {
    const path = this.pageUrl + id;
    const fetchPromise = fetch(path, {
      method: "GET",
    });

    return Promise.resolve(fetchPromise);
  }

}

export default ContentService;
```

Could anyone please advice what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPage` is an asynchronous method, that should return a promise:

```
getPage(id) {
      return this.contentService
        .getPage(id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
```

And then

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPage("1").then(model => this.setState({ model }));
  }
```

Comment: Awesome that was the problem! Thank you so much.